# Remove Suffixes from row values in each row of csv using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv where there is only one column named "FileName". I want the suffix to be removed completely after "-". The example for Input is below :-

FileName :-
folder_name-1.pdf
folder_name-2.pdf

However, the desired output from my side is :-

folder_name
folder_name

I tried using applymap as well, but it did not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and then select first values of splitted lists by indexing `str[0]`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'FileName':['folder_name-1.pdf','folder_name-2.pdf']})

df['FileName'] = df['FileName'].str.split('-').str[0]
print (df)
      FileName
0  folder_name
1  folder_name
```

Comment: it did not worked as no changes were reflected on the cell values. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Rajsxx - If not working there is some problem in data, added data from question and working perfectly.

Comment: Yeah it worked fine this time, it was a data issue because of a special character. Thanks :)